# The Python Challenge: level 3 code issues

Tags: python, string

I'm working on the Python Challenges (very fun) and I know the answer to level 3 (I peaked because I was stuck) but now I'm just curious as to why MY code didn't solve the problem correctly. I know there are other ways to solve the problem, but I want to know why MINE can't. Thanks!

"One small letter, surrounded by EXACTLY three big bodyguards on each of its sides."

So the strings I'm looking for follow this format (U = uppercase, l = lowercase):

lUUUlUUUl

```
file = open("ThePythonChallenge - 3.txt")
mess = file.read()
mess = mess.replace('\n', '')


string = ''

while mess:

    string = mess[0:9]


if string[0].islower() and string[1:4].isupper() and string[4].islower() and string[5:8].isupper() and string[8].islower():
    print(string)

mess = mess.lstrip(string)
```

But, for some reason my output is:

```
dXJVlGZVm
qKWGtIDCj
```

Which I know to be correct, but I'm missing 6 other properly formatted strings which complete the word: "l___ ___t".

Comment: `mess.lstrip(string)` removes *any of a set of characters*, not a prefix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the reply. The actual issue was my code was taking that entire sub-string and stripping it from mess, when in reality I should have been stripping just a single character and moving forward through the entire string. Thanks though!